# SQL: insert space before numbers in string

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, nvarchar

I have a `nvarchar` field in my table, which contains all sorts of strings.
In case there are strings which contain a number following a non-number sign, I want to insert a space before that number.

That is - if a certain entry in that field is `abc123`, it should be turned into `abc 123`, or `ab12.34` should become `ab 12. 34`.I want this to be done throughout the entire table.

What's the best way to achieve it?

Comment: i haven't tried anything so far, cause i don't know where to begin from...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
select left(col,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',col)-1 )+space(1)+
       case
         when PATINDEX('%[.]%',col)<>0 
           then substring(col,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',col),len(col)+1-PATINDEX('%[.]%',col))
                +space(1)+
                substring(col,PATINDEX('%[.]%',col)+1,len(col)+1-PATINDEX('%[.]%',col))
         else substring(col,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',col),len(col)+1-PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',col))
       end       
from tab
```

It's not simply, but I hope it will help you.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a0897/2)

I used functions (link to MSDN):
[LEFT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx), [PATINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx), [SPACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187950.aspx), [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms187748.aspx), [LEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx)
and [regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174214.aspx).

Comment: required some minor tweaking to fit my table's structure, but eventually did the job - cheers!